# Computing the pullback of an exterior differential of a vector field at a point given two linear independent vectors

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, pullback

Given the $1$-differential form $\omega=xzdx+xdy+xdz$ and the vector field $F(x,y,z)=(e^y,e^z,e^x)$, I must compute $$(F^{*}d\omega)_{p}(v_1,v_2)$$ where $p=(1,-1,0), v_1=(1,1,0)$ and $v_2=(1,0,1)$. This is in essence (if I am right), the *pullback of the exterior differential of the $1$-differential form $\omega$*. I get stuck almost at the end of the process, let me explain.

First of all, I have to compute the exterior differential of $\omega$ $$d\omega=dx\wedge dy+(1-x)dx\wedge dz$$Now, for the pullback $$(F^{*}d\omega)=e^y dy \wedge e^z dz + (1-e^y)e^y dy\wedge e^x dx = e^{y+z}dy\wedge dz \wedge e^x dx=e^{x+y+z}dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$$ right?

The problem comes whenever I have to apply this to my points and respective vectors. I guess that the coefficient $$e^{x+y+z}|_{(x,y,z)=(1,-1,0)}=1$$ but how do I get the final result? Please help.

Comment: Do you know that the differential and the pullback commute? If so, it is easier (in my opinion) to first compute $F^* \omega$, and then to take the differential

Comment: Plus: you have an obvious error. $d\omega$ is a $2$-form. When pulled-back by $F$, it should yield a $2$-forms... And you are writing a $3$-form (involving $dx\wedge dy \wedge dz)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to propose an answer that uses the fact that the pull-back and the exterior differential commute (a fact that is sometimes referred to as the "naturality" of the pull-back).
I personally find this approach easier since it does not require to pull-back anything more than $1$-forms.
I will give all the details to show how elementary the computations are.

Let us first compute $F^*\omega$.
We have
\begin{align}
F^*\omega
&= F^*(xzdx + xdy + xdz) \\
&= (x\circ F)(z\circ F)d(x\circ F) + (x\circ F)d(y\circ F) + (x\circ F)d(z\circ F)\\
&= e^ye^xd(e^y) + e^yd(e^z) + e^yd(e^x)\\
&= e^ye^xe^ydy + e^ye^zdz + e^ye^xdx\\
&= e^{x+y}dx + e^{x+2y}dy + e^{y+z}dz.
\end{align}
Hence, we have
\begin{align}
F^*(d\omega) &= d(F^*\omega) \\
&= d(e^{x+y})\wedge dx + d(e^{x+2y})\wedge dy + d(e^{y+z})\wedge dz \\
&= (e^{x+y}dx + e^{x+y}dy)\wedge dx + (e^{x+2y}dx + 2e^{x+2y}dy)\wedge dy + (e^{y+z}dy + e^{y+z}dz)\wedge dz\\
&= e^{x+y}dy\wedge dx + e^{x+2y}dx\wedge dy + e^{y+z}dy\wedge dz\\
&= (e^{x+2y} -e^{x+y})dx\wedge dy + e^{y+z}dy\wedge dz.
\end{align}
Therefore, at $p=(1,-1,0)$, we have
$$
d(F^*\omega)_p = (e^{-1}-1)dx\wedge dy +e^{-1}dy\wedge dz.
$$
If $v_1 = (1,1,0)$ and $v_2 = (1,0,1)$, then
\begin{align}
dx\wedge dy (v_1,v_2) &= dx(v_1)dy(v_2) - dy(v_1)dy(v_2)  \\
&=1 \times 0 - 1\times 1 \\
&= -1,\\
\text{and} \quad dy\wedge dz (v_1,v_2) &= dy(v_1)dz(v_2)-dy(v_2)dz(v_1) \\
&= 1\times 1 - 0\times 0\\
&= 1.
\end{align}
Ultimately, one has
$$
F^*(d\omega)_p(v_1,v_2) = (e^{-1}-1)\times -1 + e^{-1}\times 1 = 1.
$$

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the last  chain of equalities. You sum 2-forms and end up with a volume form. The correct pull-back, as you wrote, is:

$$ F^* d \omega = e^{y+z} dy \wedge dz - e^{x+y} (1- e^y) dx \wedge dy$$

Looking at $(v_1, v_2)$ as a 2-vector:

$$ v_1 \wedge v_2 = (e_1 + e_2 ) \wedge (e_1 + e_3)= e_1 \wedge e_3 - e_1 \wedge e_2  + e_2 \wedge e_3  .$$

And thus:

$$ (F^* d \omega)_{(1,-1,0)} (v_1, v_2 )=[e^{-1} dy \wedge dz -  (1- e^{-1}) dx \wedge dy ](e_1 \wedge e_3 - e_1 \wedge e_2  + e_2 \wedge e_3)$$

which you can compute being 1. By the way, as noted in the coments pull back and differential commute, you can try doing $d F^* \omega$ and see that the form you get is the same.

Comment: Marvelous. Now I see the error which I had commited when computing the pullback. Although, now I don't understand what you do with $v_1$ and $v_2$ saying $v_1\wedge v_2 = (e_1 + e_2)\wedge(e_1 + e_3)$. What is that? And when you substitute $v_1=(1,1,0), v_2=(1,0,1)$ how do to you get this result?

Comment: I don't know how you defined differential forms, but one way to look at them is that they take values in the dual of $k$-vectors (i.e. $k$-covectors). That's why in differential geometry they say that differential forms are a section of the cotangent bundle. Anyway, to make it short a $k$-vector is an exterior product of $k$ vectors, where $\wedge$ has the usual properties you already know ($ v \wedge v=0$, $v \wedge w = - w \wedge v$ etc). What I have done above is to choose a basis (the canonical basis) and write my 2-vectors/covectors in such a basis. If it's not clear, I'll make an edit.